# Why shifted coordinates are not valid with TiKZ fitting library?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried to use something like `([shift={(1,2)}]a.center)` as a coordinate within the list for a fitting node, but it doesn't work. With an auxiliary coordinate defined this way, it works. With an auxiliary coordinate defined with `let` expression (from `calc` library), it works also. Rectangular intersection coordinates (`|-`, `-|`) can be used with `fit` nodes.
Do you know why is not possible to use `{x|y}shift`?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};

\node[fit=(a),draw=red] {};

\coordinate (aux1) at ([shift={(-3mm,-1mm)}]a.south west);

\path let  \p2=([shift={(3mm,1mm)}]a.north east) in node [fit=(\p2)(aux1),draw=blue] {};

% Doesn't work
%\node[fit=([shift={(5mm,2mm)}]a.north east) ([shift={(-5mm,-2mm)}]a.south west), draw=green] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The argument parsing gets confused between the brackets and the braces. So the easiest is to supply the argument to `fit` in braces such that it survives the first pass.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[fit=(a),draw=red] {};
\coordinate (aux1) at ([shift={(-3mm,-1mm)}]a.south west);
\path let  \p2=([shift={(3mm,1mm)}]a.north east) in node [fit=(\p2)(aux1),draw=blue] {};
\node[fit={([shift={(5mm,2mm)}]a.north east) ([shift={(-5mm,-2mm)}]a.south west)}, draw=green]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried with braces for each shifted coordinate but not for the whole list.

Comment: @Ignasi My pleasure. Individual bracing won't work because it would pick up the first one as the argument and would get confused with the second and possibly with others.