# TikZ: Better solution than nesting tikzpicture?

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles, nesting, scoping

I created following example script to draw a TikZ that contains a nested tikz:

[image: Screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart, backgrounds, fit}

\tikzset{
  box/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=3cm,
    fill=white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

    % Box 1   
    \node[box, label={Label 1}] (Box1) {\rotatebox{90}{Content 1}};

    % Box 2 - Inner
    \node[right=of Box1] (Box2) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[box] (Inner) {\rotatebox{90}{\ttfamily{Something goes in here}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    % Box 2 - Outer
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[box, inner sep=0ex, fit=(Box2), label={Label 2}] {};
    \end{scope}

    % Box 3    
    \node[box, right=of Box2, label={Label 3}] (Box3) {\rotatebox{90}{Content 2}};

    \draw[dashed] (Box1) -- (Box2);
    \draw[dashed] (Box2) -- (Box3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Assume that the true content of `Box2`, where we currently have placeholder "Something goes in here" is a more complex TikZ drawing with many nodes.

Is it necessary to have the `\begin{tikzpicture}` within Box2, or is there a better way? I tried without, but it produced errors.

Thanks!

Comment: You may use a scope and its [`local bounding box`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144402/positioning-a-tikz-scope-relative-to-another-tikz-scope/144452#144452).

Comment: In the script above, I do make use of a scope. That means, the content of node "Box", containing mentioned tikz, is part of a scope. Should I just replace " \begin{tikzpicture}" with " \begin{scope}"?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that ...

Comment: That's what I thought, because I tried it. Do you have a solution or link?

Comment: My first comment provides a link that shows the usage of `local bounding box`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use nested `tikzpictures`

1. Start drawing the complex figure.
2. Put a `fit` node aroung it on `background` layer.
3. Draw Box1 to the left.
4. Draw Box2 to the right.

Reordered code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart, backgrounds, fit}

\tikzset{
  box/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=3cm,
    fill=white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]


    % Box 2 - Inner
            \node[box, font=\ttfamily, text width=2cm] (a) {Something goes in here};
            \node[box, circle, below right=2mm and 5mm of a, font=\ttfamily, text width=2cm]  (b) {Something goes in here};

%    % Box 2 - Outer
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[box, inner sep=1ex, fit=(a) (b), label={Label 2}] (Box2) {};
    \end{scope}

    % Box 1   
    \node[box, label={Label 1}, left =of Box2 ] (Box1) {\rotatebox{90}{Content 1}};


    % Box 3    
    \node[box, right=of Box2, label={Label 3}] (Box3) {\rotatebox{90}{Content 2}};

    \draw[dashed] (Box1) -- (Box2);
    \draw[dashed] (Box2) -- (Box3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that my graphic looks like described here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368345/how-to-create-a-schematic-representation-of-a-neural-network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368345/how-to-create-a-schematic-representation-of-a-neural-network) . So there's more than node elements (i.e. pic + draw +path)?

Comment: Inside the `fit` list you can include what you want, nodes or coordinates or shifted coordinates. To surround a complex picture you just need two cleverly selected coordinates. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47708/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204807/1952